# How to see if first character of a string is " " (a string starting with ")

Tags: java, compiler-errors, lexer

```
static boolean isLiteralTexto(String lexema) {
           String letra = [34];
            String caracter = "";
            int estado = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < lexema.length(); i++) {
                caracter = lexema.charAt(i) + "";
                switch (estado) {
                case 1:
                    if (caracter.matches(letra))
                        estado = 2;
                                    System.out.println("HOLA");
                    else
                        estado = 3;
                    break;
```

I dont know how to make it, is JAVA could you help me?
 Im doing a lexer and a parser

Comment: `if (lexema.startsWith(" "))` *or* `if (lexema.charAt(0) == ' ')`

Comment: [`String#startsWith(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Can you describe you problem in more detail? What do you want to do and why? What have you tried? Why didn't that work for you? What error are you getting?

Comment: `lexema.charAt(0) == ' '`?

Comment: well Im doing a compiler of my own language, is a proyect with a lot of classes so I have to identify a text literal... something that we know as code lines as this "hi" so I want to check the first line of my file and identify if the firsr character is an "" to say that is a literal

Answer (score 1):

Use standart java: yourstring.startsWith(" ");

Answer (score 0):

you can check using the following snippet: 
if(lexema.indexOf(" ")==0)